# Extra white space on bottom of website

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website and can't figure out where this extra whitespace is coming from. I tried using different padding and margin scenarios, but I can't get it to work.

```
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Last few lines of html..

```
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Screenshot of bottom of site https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcOnL.png

Not sure what else you would need to figure this out, please let me know. I was reading and it seems there is some set margin that has to be fixed.

Comment: screenshot? more code?

Comment: Use a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: It is difficult to find from where comes the whitespaces at the end without the full html and css code.

Comment: You can always use inspect element as a guide if you encounter errors like this. If you are using google chrome by simply right clicking on the part of the website that you think is wrong and clicking inspect element you might find the problem.

Comment: Based off the screenshot, this is different to what I was thinking. Much larger than what I was expecting. Could you post the code somewhere (unless it's massive)?

Answer (score 1):

**If you are trying to remove all padding**

```
html, body{
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Browsers often automatically add this padding.

Comment: didn't work :/ not sure what else I can provide to figure it out

Comment: @stack_newbie23 can you provide the full html, also are you using any plugins like jquery mobile that might add the whitespace

Answer (score 1):

All pages have padding on them. To remove this, you can use this in your stylesheet:

```
* { // asterisk meaning 'all elements'
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Using `*` is a high price to pay for that matter

Comment: @ring0 I know, but that's just how I've done it in the past, and it works. There will be better ways of doing it, but that's just what I know.

Comment: Yeah, that seems better.

Comment: Is there anyway I can show you my entire html and css code? Very small site

Comment: You could try uploading the file to a file sharing website, like Dropbox and giving us the link?

Answer (score 0):

edit:

The problem comes from `#content div` that is out of the flow (since it is a float), and have a height of 100%, but since it is out of the flow, the percentage refers to the whole page size but not to this container. To solve the problem, you need to give it the same height than his container (80%):

```
#content div {
    float: left;
    height: 80%;
}
```

old answer:

I think that your white space come from your html code. Removes all white spaces between your last closing tag and the closing body tag.

example:

```
    </div>
</body>
```

=>

```
    </div></body>
```

Comment: HTML ignores all whitespace, similar to most languages. This won't change anything.

Comment: @sparklyllama: It's false, HTML doesn't ignore whitespaces, it only reduces several whitespaces to one space character. What are the languages you are speaking about?

Comment: @sparklyllama Can you post a JS fiddle with your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8S4xN/1/ here you go.. you still may need to pull the code out, it looks funny on jsfiddle

Comment: hmmm I did that and I still have the whitespace. Did you set padding and margin to 0 for html & body?

Comment: @stack_newbie23: I used a copy/paste of your code, If I set the height to 80%, the vertical scrollbar disappears. But do you want that the content takes the whole height?

Comment: @stack_newbie23: one of the problems is that you use a fixed height for the nav part. A better way is to put the nav part as an absolute positioned block in the container with the fixed height you want and to use an equal padding-top for the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your browser's property inspector. Just right click the specific part of your web page and click Inspect Element (if you're in Google Chrome). Firebug is a Firefox/Safari/IE plugin that works the same way. From the inspector you can turn on/off css styles and see what the styles are behind a block of content. Write down the css style and edit the css file outside of your browser.